# How to understand snprintf's processing NULL argument?

Tags: c

Check following simple `C` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[4] = {1, 1, 1, 1};
    snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%s%s", "a", NULL);

    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Build and run it on `Linux`:

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
a(n
```

How to understand "`(n`" characters which come after `a` in the output? I expect when `snprintf` come across `NULL` argument, it will stop processing. BTW, I can't find related information from `snprintf` [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf).

Comment: `NULL` and `'\0'` are not the same, are you aware of that? I.e. try `""` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why `snprintf` write `"(null)"` when come across `NULL`? Is there any document? Thx!

Comment: @NanXiao: Neither the C standard nor the POSIX standard specifies that the `printf()` family of functions will print `(null)` when a NULL pointer is passed to them.  The GNU C Library (amongst others) does so because otherwise programs crash when a NULL pointer is printed and it is a common mistake for beginners to make (and presumably for more experienced users too).  Personally, I regard it as a clear case where the code should call `abort()` and regard the substitution of `(null)` is unwarranted nannyism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `snprintf` (`fprintf`, `printf` or any function from that family) comes across a null pointer argument for a `%s` format specifier, the behavior is undefined. In real life instead of crashing or behaving unpredictably many Standard Library implementations prefer to insert a `(null)` sequence into the recipient buffer. This is what you observe in your experiment - the beginning of that `(null)` that `snprintf` managed to fit into the remaining space of that `str` recipient array.

---

There was a story a long time ago (even Internet, which never forgets, seems to have forgotten about it), about an ordinary customer of a large US telecommunication company, who registered "null" as his email ID, thus getting "null@company.com" as his email address. Suddenly he started receiving a large amount of internal company's emails containing other customers' personal data. If I remember correctly, it was caused by a bug in internal company's software, where a null pointer was passed to a function responsible for forming the destination email addresses. And that function, instead of crashing, resorted to a similar fail-safe behavior in response to a null-pointer argument. The bug remained unnoticed until someone actually registered "null@company.com" as a valid email address.

Comment: I tried to find a quote for that being UB. Can you provide one? Best I have is "The argument must be a pointer to the initial element of an array of characters." from http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @Yunnosch: 7.21.6.1/8 "the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type.". Null pointer does not meet that requirement.

Comment: Does not meeting a requirement imply "undefined" or "unspecified"?

Comment: @Yunnosch: Undefined, of course. "Unspecified" cannot be implied. It has to be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

The `snprintf` function tries to write `"(null)"` into your string, but since the destination is only four characters you can never get more than a three-character string (plus terminator).

Note that the insertion of `"(null)"` is not specified by the standard, passing a NULL argument for the `"%s"` format specifier is really [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I tried to find a quote for that being UB. Can you provide one? Best I have is "The argument must be a pointer to the initial element of an array of characters." from en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

Comment: @Yunnosch: [C11 §7.1.4 Use of library functions ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1) — _Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed
descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, […] the behavior is undefined._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is what I was looking for.